# Tkinter first or PyQt?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to solidify my python knowledge by doing some gui development, should I try Tkinter or jump directly to PyQT for better IDE support?

Comment: What sorts of GUI's would you be looking to build?

Comment: Well I'm just starting for the moment, so after I learn the basics I'll go for a cross-platform calculator based on the Windows calculator in standard mode. Adfter that who knows, maybe something more complex like a dispatch application using Google or Bing Maps.

Comment: I agree with the answer, tkinter is probably better for your needs!

Answer (score 2):

If your main goal is to solidify your python knowledge, I would recommend Tkinter. It's simpler and it's already installed with Python.

If you want to build complex applications, I recommend PyQt, which is way more powerful.

Comment: Would a cross-platform calculator based on the Windows calc in standard mode be simple enough for Tkinter?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. You will only need several buttons and a text widget.

Comment: The way you organize your layouts is up to you. I think you will use a few layouts, not just one. However, I guess grid layout is a very good choice to organize the buttons

Comment: What widget can be the container for a text widget and a grid?

Comment: I think "Way more powerful" is a bit of an exaggeration. While you can't easily do a bunch of pretty shiny animations or embed web pages, for most of what people use python gui toolkits for tkinter is plenty powerful.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a big difference between PyQt5 and Tkinter in long-running loops and dealing with the GUI freezing.

In both Tkinger and PyQt5, the GUI will freeze during long loops because the GUI update procedures aren't being called. To fix this in Tkinter I add this code:

**Tkinter Solution**

```
def update_app():
    root_winwod.update_idletasks()
    root_winwod.update()

for x in range(10000):
    if x % 100 = 0: # Triggers after 100 iterations. You can change this for your needs.
        update_app()
    
    # The rest of your loop code here
```

**PyQt5 Solution**

For PyQt5 you could call `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` but all the websites say not to do this. Instead, you have to create a subprocess, create multiprocess safe variables with multiprocessing.Manager(), make sure that you lock and unlock the variables as you access them, use subprocess.check_output() to try and catch errors in your subprocess, add a Qtimer() to update the UI on a regular interval, make sure that you kill the processes when the app exits and so on.

For simple apps, I would suggest running Tkinter. Running subprocesses is fine, it just takes a lot of additional coding and effort to make sure that you get everything right.